# What does Clojure’s bit-and-not do?

Tags: clojure

From the [docs](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bit-and-not):

> #### bit-and-not
>
> function
>
> ```
> Usage: (bit-and-not x y)
>        (bit-and-not x y & more)
>
> Bitwise and with complement
> ```
>
> Added in Clojure version 1.0

Clojure's other bit- functions make sense to me, but I don't understand this one.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#andNot%28java.math.BigInteger%29. It's existence in Clojure is probably mirroring that in BigInteger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to this:

`(bit-and x (bit-not y))`

This function can be used to do subset tests. The set `a` (represented as a bitmask) is a subset of the set `b` if and only if `(bit-and-not a b)` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. It looks like when your Clojure code is compiled to JVM bytecodes, calls to `(bit-and-not)` are converted to calls to `clojure.lang.Numbers.andNot()`, which looks like this:

```
static public long andNot(long x, long y){
     return x & ~y;
}
```

So perhaps this is for performance, if you need to do a bitwise AND with complement inside an inner loop?

The most common use case for a bitwise AND with complement is when you are working with bitmasks -- to clear all the bits in `x` which are set in `y`. Or perhaps there is some other reason why this is a particularly useful operation?

Comment: I just searched on GitHub for Clojure code which uses `(bit-and-not)`. It is very rarely used. In all the projects on GH, there are just a couple which use it. One use was for extracting some information from binary data, using a bitmask.

Comment: I would imagine that bitwise operations in general are rare, even in java.

Comment: Here is one practical application: subset test. The set `a` (represented as a bitmask) is a subset of the set `b` if and only if `(bit-and-not a b)` is zero.

Comment: @tom, would you mind adding your comment to your answer? It's very helpful.